# Attention OCR (FSNS) with smaller charset

Tags: tensorflow, ocr, attention-model

We are trying to train the Attention OCR (FSNS) with a smaller charset (file) of  [38 chars](https://gist.github.com/ashish1405/5a97394e8f8e5d1cb4c46bd949aa3d68). We have our own image dataset which is similar in nature to the FSNS dataset. 
Now the problem we are facing is, after even four days of training the loss keeps on increasing and reaches in thousands. But if we use the default charset file `charset_size\=134.txt`, loss does not increase and we get character accuracy ~= .80 and word accuracy ~= .50. But the when we do evaluation using demo_inference.py, our model gives junk output. 
We are not using gpu. Tensorflow versions tried (1.2,1.3).

Can someone please help us on this?

Comment: This sounds like an ML question, not a programming one. You might have better luck on stats.stackexchange.com. Also, you might want to include more detailed information for somebody to help you.

Comment: thanks, we have kind off solved it, once confirmed will post the solution.

Comment: @Ashishail have you got the solution already?